# why my own AtomicLong are slower than the one provide in the JDK?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, compare-and-swap, atomic-long

I was writing my own `AtomicLong` class and I just found that the function I had is much slower than the one provided in the Unsafe class. I am wondering why?

Below are the codes I have:

```java
public interface Counter {
    void increment();
    long get();
}


public class PrimitiveUnsafeSupportCounter implements Counter{

    private volatile long count = 0;
    private Unsafe unsafe;
    private long offset;

    public PrimitiveUnsafeSupportCounter() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        this.unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);
        this.offset = this.unsafe.objectFieldOffset(PrimitiveUnsafeSupportCounter.class.getDeclaredField("count"));
    }

    @Override
    public void increment() {

        this.unsafe.getAndAddLong(this, this.offset, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public long get() {
        return this.count;
    }
}

public class CounterThread implements Runnable {

    private Counter counter;

    public CounterThread(Counter counter){
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i ++){
            this.counter.increment();
        }
    }
}

class Test{

    public static void test(Counter counter) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000; i++){
            executor.submit(new CounterThread(counter));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(counter.get());
        System.out.println(stop - start);
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, InterruptedException {

        Counter primitiveUnsafeSupportCounter = new PrimitiveUnsafeSupportCounter();
        Test.test(primitiveUnsafeSupportCounter);

    }

}
```

it takes about 3000ms to finish the above codes.
however, it takes about even 7000ms if I used the below codes instead of `this.unsafe.getAndAddLong(this, this.offset, 1);`.

```java
long before;
do {
     before = this.unsafe.getLongVolatile(this, this.offset);
} while (!this.unsafe.compareAndSwapLong(this, this.offset, before, before + 1));
```

I went through the source codes of `getAndAddLong` and found it does nearly the same thing as the above codes, so what should I miss?

Comment: You might be missing that the JVM is intimately familiar with the `Unsafe` class and likely has fully optimized native code for `getAndAddLong` method. Your `do-while` loop may not JIT-compile the same as that fully optimized native code.

Answer (score 0):

That's JVM intrinsic and hand-written loop version has highly inefficient compiled code for the purpose. On x86 you can have atomic version of such read-modify-write operations via `lock` prefix. See Intel Manual *8.1.2.2 Software Controlled Bus Locking* :

> To explicitly force the LOCK semantics, software can use the LOCK
>   prefix with the following instructions when they are used to modify
>   a memory location.

In particular you can have something like `lock add op1 op2`. In your example you test the result  of `cmpxchg` and do some jump which is obviously slower. Also as far as I remember on x86 volatile access requires some sort of `mfence` or `lock` to ensure memory ordering.